# React Native console log proxy object

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was following a `react-native` tutorial, but I encounter some weird result.

Here is the code

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return({
      tasks: ['Take Course', "Clean house"],
      task: ''
    })
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
          ToDoList
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style = {styles.inputbox}
          placeholder="Type task"
          onChange={(text) => {
            this.setState({task: text});
            console.log(this.state.task);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
})
```

I want to use `console.log` to print `text` which is coming from `TextInput`.

Here is the simulator.
[image]

I was expecting that it will print `1`, `12` and `123` in chrome console.

But I got this [image]

Why it prints this `proxy` object, and what is this object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`. Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Moreover `this.setState` is an asynchronous call, that means it is undetermined when state will be set. In that case you have to call console.log as a callback to be sure that state has changed.

```
this.setState({
   task: text
}, () => {
   console.log(this.state.task)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to `react-native`. I will check your suggestion.